# Get video duration with YouTube Data API?

Tags: jquery, html, css, youtube, youtube-data-api

Basically, I'm trying to get the video duration of each video that shows up in the results when they search. I have a neat little demo set up for you to mess with!

ALSO - When I say duration I mean the length of the video in M/S format (0:00)..

**DEMO** http://codepen.io/mistkaes/pen/6b6a347c7d24edee15b3491420db4ecd

**jQuery:**

```
var apikey = '<API KEY>';

$(function() {
    var searchField = $('#search-input');

    $('#search-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

function search() {
    $('#results').html('');

    q = $('#search-input').val();

    $.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", {
            part: 'snippet, id',
            q: q,
            maxResults: 50,
            type: 'video',
            key: apikey
        },
        function(data) {
            $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                var output = getResults(item);

                $('#results').append(output);
            });
        });
}

function getResults(item) {
    var videoID = item.id.videoId;
    var title = item.snippet.title;
    var thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url;
    var channelTitle = item.snippet.channelTitle;

    var output = '<li>' +
        '<div class="list-left">' +
        '<img src="' + thumb + '">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="list-right">' +
        '<h3><a href="http://youtube.com/embed/' + videoID + '?rel=0">' + title + '</a></h3>' +
        '<p class="cTitle">' + channelTitle + '</p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</li>' +
        '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
        '';

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer hope it helps you .

Comment: BTW, this is really late, but important. Don't post your API keys! These are private. Someone can now abuse your quota.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I searched your query and found there's an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4294) with the search api.

The alternative is to make a call to the [Youtube Data API's](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) Video resource after you make the search call. You can put up to 50 video id's in search, so you won't have to call it for each element

I updated your [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOLYQN?editors=001) and what I done was the following:

**1)** Get Url of each video that you got from search.

**2)** Send an another Ajax call to get duration:-

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
    var url1 = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + data.items[i].id.videoId + "&key=AIzaSyDYwPzLevXauI-kTSVXTLroLyHEONuF9Rw&part=snippet,contentDetails";
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: url1,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.items.length > 0) {
                var output = getResults(data.items[0]);
                $('#results').append(output);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**3)** The API give time in ISO format so I converted it into `mm:ss` format (as you wanted).

```
function convert_time(duration) {
    var a = duration.match(/\d+/g);

    if (duration.indexOf('M') >= 0 && duration.indexOf('H') == -1 && duration.indexOf('S') == -1) {
        a = [0, a[0], 0];
    }

    if (duration.indexOf('H') >= 0 && duration.indexOf('M') == -1) {
        a = [a[0], 0, a[1]];
    }
    if (duration.indexOf('H') >= 0 && duration.indexOf('M') == -1 && duration.indexOf('S') == -1) {
        a = [a[0], 0, 0];
    }

    duration = 0;

    if (a.length == 3) {
        duration = duration + parseInt(a[0]) * 3600;
        duration = duration + parseInt(a[1]) * 60;
        duration = duration + parseInt(a[2]);
    }

    if (a.length == 2) {
        duration = duration + parseInt(a[0]) * 60;
        duration = duration + parseInt(a[1]);
    }

    if (a.length == 1) {
        duration = duration + parseInt(a[0]);
    }
    var h = Math.floor(duration / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(duration % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(duration % 3600 % 60);
    return ((h > 0 ? h + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" : "") : "") + m + ":" + (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s);
}
```

**4)** Append your result with title of your video.

```
'<p class="cTitle">' + channelTitle + '  --->' + duration + '</p>'
```